# Google UAC - Branch.io Queries

Tags: branch.io, google-ads-api

As you know that in the Google UAC there is linkless campaign. Then how can we use Branch Attribution? I mean my major agenga here is to get a postback to our database on which campaign is resulting in which sorts of user. Please help me here

Answer (score 0):

Google UAC are definitely linkless campaigns but Branch offers a seamless integration here in order to help you track and attribute to monitor your marketing channels.

You would need to connect your Branch dashboard to your admin google adwords account with the respective link ids created for the app to be tracked.
You have to import the events to Google Adwords conversions, and align the attribution windows and timezone as per your Branch dashboard.

Post integration and setup, Branch will automatically track and attribute events to Google Adwords as per last touch attribution logic. You will be able to see campaign level data as well on dashboard.

Requesting you to refer to our documentation for a better understanding on the same : https://docs.branch.io/deep-linked-ads/google-ads-setup/#overview